# How do you differentiate between the process and thread in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, process

From what I understand, thread and process differs in that thread shares resources.

I am not sure if this differs from one language to another, but how do you differentiate between
thread and process in general or in Python?

Are every independent functions different process?
Would a class methods be threads as they share memory? would recursive functions be thread?

If threading or processing module is not used, how can it be differentiated? and
IS there a need to differentiate them?

Thank you

Comment: Functions and classes have no relationship to threads and processes. It sounds like you need to do some reading on what these things are. Threads and processes are very specific things, not just a general name for things that happen to share resources or not.

Comment: I think you're confusing threads with the other constructs. Unless you (or a library you're using) explicitly create a `Thread` or `Process`, everything will run in the same thread and the same process. You often only have a single thread running in a single process, unless you're needing to speed up I/O or computations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer your questions directly:

> From what I understand, thread and process differs in that thread shares resources.

This is not true, at least not from your understanding. Consider that you can edit a file in `Notepad` and in `WordPad` at the same time; both are different processes sharing the same resource; a file in this case.

Conceptually, a *process* is a single "application" that shares the resources of the operating system and other processes while a *thread* is a single "execution context" that shares the same basic resources of a *process*.

It's a little more complicated than that, but at a high level that's the basic difference between a process and a thread.

> I am not sure if this differs from one language to another, but how do you differentiate between thread and process in general or in Python?

Given the prior point, in a general basic context, a thread is owned by a process, and every process has at least **one** thread.

From a *code* perspective, you can differentiate by getting the process ID and thread ID, and that *does* depend on your langauge.

For Python, you would `import os` and then call [`os.getpid()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getegid) to get the current *process* ID, and if you're using Python 3.8 you can call [`threading.get_native_id()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.get_native_id) to get the thread id from which the function is currently executed on.

If you were to create 10 threads within the same process, each thread should return the same value for `os.getpid()` but should return 10 different ID's for `threading.get_native_id()`.

Additionally, a thread within a process can spawn another thread **or** *separate* process. For example, a single process (read: application) could create 10 threads, and in each thread could spawn an external application (read: process), but that process is not *owned* by the thread that spawned it like the thread is *owned* by the process that spawned it.

Another basic way to think of it, all *processes* are children of the OS, and all *threads* are children of the parent *process*, no matter which thread or process created what.

> Are every independent functions different process? Would a class methods be threads as they share memory? would recursive functions be thread?

No. Each function lives within the same process memory space, including classes and their member functions. Recursive functions are neither processes nor threads, they are functions that call themselves.

You could create a thread that calls a specific function, and that function could potentially be recursive, but again, you have to have your code specifically create a thread and utilize the function address which lives within the process created when your `init` code was called (`main` in other languages).

> If threading or processing module is not used, how can it be differentiated?

Referring again to the previous points, you differentiate it by understanding what a [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) is and what a [thread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)) is.

> and IS there a need to differentiate them?

Yes. Conceptually they are different things, and once you actually start doing various types of multi-threaded, multi-process, memory-mapped code, you do need to understand that difference and how it pertains to your code.

At a bare minimum, if you never write a single line of multi-threaded code in your career, it is important to at least understand how they relate.